Running tests on azure devops agent that adjust date/time
I have automated test plans in azure devops.I have an agent configured for them. I kick off a run of a certain plan that during the tests alters the local date/time to manipulate various data. However when it does this the agent loses contact and the run gets aborted..
I have seen two errors once the date/time is changed in the test.
One:

Agent connect error: The bearer  is not valid until 26/06/2024 19:30:52. Current server time is 24/06/2024 19:30:51.. Retrying until reconnected.

Two:

Date/time out of sync and cannot connect

How can I get around this issue? Surely this must be something people do see and there is a work around? Devops ops self hosted and not cloud based. The agent isn't running as a service.

The cause of the issue is that Time mismatch between the Azure DevOps Service and the Agent machine time after tests changing the local date/time.
Refer to the Agent configuration code: ConfigurationManager.cs

Testing agent connection, detect any protential connection issue, like local clock skew that cause OAuth token expired.

        _term.WriteLine(StringUtil.Loc("TestAgentConnection"));
        var credMgr = HostContext.GetService<ICredentialManager>();
        VssCredentials credential = credMgr.LoadCredentials();
        var agentSvr = HostContext.GetService<IAgentServer>();
        try
        {
            await agentSvr.ConnectAsync(new Uri(agentSettings.ServerUrl), credential);
        }
        catch (VssOAuthTokenRequestException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("Current server time is"))
        {
            // there are two exception messages server send that indicate clock skew.
            // 1. The bearer token expired on {jwt.ValidTo}. Current server time is {DateTime.UtcNow}.
            // 2. The bearer token is not valid until {jwt.ValidFrom}. Current server time is {DateTime.UtcNow}.
            Trace.Error("Catch exception during test agent connection.");
            Trace.Error(ex);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(StringUtil.Loc("LocalClockSkewed"));
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ExceptionsUtil.HandleSocketException(ex, agentSettings.ServerUrl, Trace.Error);
            throw;
        }

This is a hard connection check in Azure DevOps Agent. When your local time does not match Azure DevOps, it will report this error. This is an expected behavior.
I am afraid that there is no method can skip this check in Azure DevOps Agents for the time being. So the tests that change the time will not run as expected in Azure DevOps
We need to make sure the time zones are in sync.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
